# Which wires go where in this non-standard GET dimmer switch?

Tags: wiring, dimmer-switch

I am replacing some touch sensitive dimmers - where the touch doesn't work half the time - with another unit made my GET, I think.

The manufacturer has decided on making up their own naming and hieroglyphics for the terminals; L, Sw and a wavy line with an arrow through it.

[image]

The old switch has L1, L2 and COM which is fairly standard.

How do I wire this? Thanks.

Comment: Did the device come with instructions, or any type of documentation?

Comment: Sadly not. They were boxed, but neither of the two units had a slip. I've done it anyway, based on some schematic I found on Google Images.

Comment: Those symbols are used in electronic engineering which is usually *not* carried outside to electrical devices.  As you figured out, L is "line", the wavy line with the arrow is output variable AC voltage.

Comment: Thanks, me from 8 years ago. I was wiring another one like this in and I bunched all blue commons into a tiny junction box I found in my bag and just ignored Sw. I know view brown and blue wires as just left and right sides of a circuit where both are live, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I wired:

- L to permanent live.
- Sw to nothing, which my best guess is for signalling between >1 GET switch.
- Wavey-line-arrow to the load/driver.

Here's a diagram I found that is very similar (my unit has 'Sw' whereas the diagram has 'S').

[image]

Comment: The unit has up, on/off, and down. An interesting behaviour was that the dim-down button was switching the power off on both units when I first powered-up the ring and tested them. I thought they were broken but after turning them off and moaning loudly, Googling, I returned and they were fine! Though the down button does power off if tapped and dims if held, so maybe I was tapping on my first try out.